# How this xpath and contains function works in the following xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, facebook-php-webdriver

I've a xpath with **contains** function. I don't know what **.,** in contains() mean and how does this xpath work? Can anybody please tell me? Thanks.

```
xpath('//div[label//text()[contains(., "Faculty")]]//input')
```

Answer (score 2):

`.` references current context node, which in your case is text node since the `.` resides in the predicate expression (expression within `[]`) for `text()`. Break down of your XPath expression :

- **`//div[...]`** : find `div` elements, anywhere in the document, where...
- **`label`** : the `div` has child element `label`
- **`//text()[contains(., "Faculty")]`**: and the label contains descendant text nodes where the value of the text node contains literal 'Faculty'
- **`//input`**: from such `div` that satisfy all the above criteria, return descendant elements `input`

Answer (score 0):

so xpath is `//div[label//text()[contains(., "Faculty")]]//input`

> `//div[...]//input` searches for all inputs in all divs that matches  special condition in brackets

The condition is `label//text()[contains(., "Faculty")]`

> so the above div should have direct child (on 1st level) in which on any level below item with text containing "Faculty" exists